# Energy low after weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, energy

During two quite active weeks, I lost about three kilos. After those weeks, I have been feeling low on energy, and more affected by how much food I have eaten the last few hours than before.

In other words, in the past I could go without food for hours without feeling like I was low on energy. After the two aforementioned weeks, I can no longer do that. Is this normal?

I have to add that I am about 180 cm tall and now weigh 87 kilos. So, I am definitely not underweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds overwhelmingly likely that the caloric deficit that lead to the 3kg/2weeks was a bit too much.

(For reference, *caloric deficit* means we consume less calories than we spend per day.)

If your goal is continued weight loss, I would recommend adding some more carbohydrates to your diet. Yes, it means increasing your caloric intake, but like I said, it sounds like your low caloric intake is causing your lack of energy.

A very good way of adding *good* carbohydrates throughout the day, is chomping on some fruit every now and then. If it's been a couple hours since your last meal, your blood sugar might decrease, causing a feeling of low energy. Fruits are high in natural sugars, and will help combat that, and provide a boost in energy.

When we lose weight too fast, it's very likely that a good portion of that weight loss is muscle atrophy.

If, instead of losing 3kgs over two weeks, you start to lose 1kg every two weeks, that's a far more healthy rate of weight loss.